# Showing that $D - a K$ is ample for some sufficiently large $a>0$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

My question arises from the proof of theorem 1.4 in https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/sites.bc.edu/dist/a/54/files/2019/12/nefcone.pdf

For a projective klt pair $(X,\Delta)$, the Mori cone theorem says that $$\overline{NE}(X)= \overline{NE}(X)_{K_X+\Delta \ge 0} + \sum \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0} [C_j] $$
For countably many rational curves $C_j$. In the first paragraph of the proof, we have a divisor $D$ such that $D$ is positive on $\overline{NE}(X)_{K_X + \Delta\ge 0}$, i.e $D\cdot C > 0$ for all $[C]\in \overline{NE}(X)_{K_X+\Delta \ge 0}$, and negative somewhere on $\overline{NE}(X)$.

In what follows, the author claims that after rescaling, $D = K_X + \Delta +A$ for some ample divisor. My question is, how do we arrive at the existence of such an ample $A$? I can only show that $D - a(K_X + \Delta)$ is a divisor positive on $\overline{NE}(X)_{K_X+\Delta \ge 0}$ for some sufficiently small $a>0$. To show that it is ample, I have to show that it is positive on the whole cone $\overline{NE}(X)$. How do I do this?

Any hints/help given should be greatly appreciated! Let me know if more details are needed.

Comment: As he says, this is Lemma 4.3; what part of its proof is the issue?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the reply. May I know how does he conclude in the proof of 4.3 that $D$ being positive on $\overline{NE}(X)_{K_X+\Delta=0}$ implies that  $\overline{NE}(X)_{K_X+\Delta\ge 0}$? It seem to suggest that for a $V$ bounding divisor $D$, if $\alpha \in \overline{NE}(X)_{K_X+\Delta>0}$ then $D\cdot \alpha >0.$ how do we see this?

Comment: I think he is just summarizing since the full proof is cited from a paper of Araujo. It looks a bit intricate so I cannot just extract the point at the moment, but it's Claim 4.2 in here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0502174v1.pdf

Comment: I have looked at the paper by Araujo and I'm able to follow. I just have trouble following the exposition by Brian. I think I will just follow Araujo's proof for now. Thank you so much!